# validating a form using get method in django

Tags: python, django

I hope my question is not very basic. Here I am trying to taking the input and showing output on the same page.
I went through an article that said I should use `GET` method to do so.

my `view`

```
def calc(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = CalculationForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            number1 = form.cleaned_data.get('first_number')
            number2 = form.cleaned_data.get('second_number')
            sum = number1 + number2
            sum.save()
            return render(request, 'calculation\calculator.html', {'sum': sum})
    else:
        form = CalculationForm()
    return render(request, 'calculation\calculator.html', {'form': form})
```

my `HTML`

```
<body>
    <form  method="get" action=".">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="Register"  value="Submit" />
    {{sum}}
</body>
```

Here I am showing the user simple form

- user input numbers in two fields
- Add the numbers
- showing it back to the user on the same page

My form is getting rendered and the fields are displaying I am able to enter the number in the field but when I click submit I get an error. Anyone

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error, you should show it in your question, rather than just saying "I get an error".

The main issue here is that the request method is always GET, because that's how your form is being submitted. So your if statement is always true, even on first display of the page.

You need to switch on something else. One idea would be to use the fact that the Submit button is an input like the others, so would be included in the submitted data. So:

```
if 'Submit' in request.GET:
    form = CalculationForm(request.GET)
    ...
```

Note that you will have another error, when you call `sum.save()`. The `sum` here is an integer, so it's not clear what you are trying to do when you call "save" on it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, changed my `if` loop and removed the `sum.save()` but still, the `sum` is not displayed in the HTML